# How to horizontal center all the columns (as they are one) in listview

Tags: wpf

I want to align all the columns to the center in listview without having a scrollbar on the bottom, which I had while trying this:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right" />
</Style>
```

and that code didn't work for me, because all the columns were still aligning left:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkmPr.png

I want it to look like this (modified in Paint)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KscQX.png
Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without seeing the XAML source code, but what I think you need to do is set the `HorizontalAlignment` of that bottom `ListView` to `Center`.

The fact that the scroll bar is appearing in your image, even though there is more than enough room for the visible items, makes me think that there are other items in your `ListView` which are not visible but are still taking up space. This might interfere with the sizing of the `ListView` and make it bigger than it should be, so I would suggest looking into that next.